# PHP - Add link to a URL in a string if not present

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Lets say i had a string as in $str ::

```
$str = "Test,

Here\'s an interesting in-house litigation position with JPMorgan Chase in New York I thought you might be interested inL

<a href="http://www.example.com/lcdetail.php?akey=e1725">http://www.example.com/lcdetail.php?akey=e1725</a>

They are not using recruiters to fill this job, so if you are interested you can just apply directly.  

http://www.example.com/lcdetail.php?akey=e1725

Cordially
--Harrison";
```

Now i want to added  tag to the links whom  tag is not present.

I had used this function but not returning desired value.

```
function processString($s){  
  return preg_replace('@(?<!href=")(https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&=+\*\'(),\/]+)((?!\<\/\a\>).)*@i','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$s);
}
```

My requirement is NOT to ADD anchor tag in link if it is present and ADD to those which haven't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I just modified your lookbehind path to `(?<!href="|">)` to avoid the link inside the tags...

So use :

```
function processString($s){  
  return preg_replace('@(?<!href="|">)(https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&=+\*\'(),\/]+)((?!\<\/\a\>).)*@i','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$s);
}
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN6gQ1)

[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/6Wzpj8Hf)